# $('body').on('blur') not working well in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to trigger a function on `$('body').on('blur')`

The below code is working fine in all browser except IE8

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(window).focus();
            $(window).on("focus", function () {

                  //  alert("w");
             });
            $(window).on("blur", function () {
               alert("window blur");

            });

            $('body').on("blur", function () {
                alert("body blur");
            });


            jQuery('body').bind("focus", function (event) {
                    alert("body focus");
            });

            jQuery('body').bind("blur", function (event) {
                alert("body blur bind");
            });

        });
```

Now the problem I am facing in IE is

the body.blur is working fine as long as i click inside the document

after that its getting triggered only after i come back to the document

Comment: Please update your browser and try it again. Because IE8 is not support some later jquery version and html5 too?

Comment: The support of the blur event on different elements is browser dependent. Here is an overview of the support for [blur event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html).

Comment: But IE8 compatibility is needed !! thats why i am trying for it :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2.*?  If so, you might want to switch to 1.10.* as support was removed for IE < 9 in 2.*.

Comment: @AlanShortis I am using 1.9 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.selected_option').bind('focusout', function(){
  alert('focusout');
});
```

**It works for me,Check it once**

Answer (score 1):

You could add attribute on the document body as follows:

```
<body onblur="alert('blur')">
```

OR you can add this attribute to the body using jQuery as follows:

```
jQuery("body").attr("onblur","alert('blur')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

blur event will not work consistently across browsers, use **focusout** instead and also bind is deprecated so use **on** instead

```
$('.selected_option').on('focusout', function(){
 //TODO your code
});
```